# Why SS generated all Int data type to bool?

Tags: subsonic, int, boolean

My Db have some fields using Integer data type, but after SS generated them, all of them 're Boolean db type.

Please tell me how to fix it !

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried regenerating?  And to be clear: the classes' types are all Boolean, the database types didn't change; right?

Comment: Everything done ! Just change type 'tinyint' to 'int' ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tinyint will be flagged as boolean since many databases use that for true/false. It's a choice we had to make for MySQL which I understand could cause issues.

If you use SubSonic 3, you can change this in the templates.